# How to fix cells cut in Seaborn clustermap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a correlation matrix with seaborn.clustermap.
However, exterior cells are being cut as you can see. Despite browsing the forum i could not find a relevant answer, but i believe it is due because of the lenght of my x/yticks.

[image: cluster map]

Here the Python code :

```
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(10, 220, as_cmap=True)

cm = sns.clustermap(ma.corr(),annot=True,fmt='.2f', cmap=cmap, center=0, square=True, linewidths=0.01,xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)

cm.ax_row_dendrogram.set_visible(False)
cm.ax_col_dendrogram.set_visible(False)

dendro_box = cm.ax_row_dendrogram.get_position()
dendro_box.x0 = (dendro_box.x0 + 2 * dendro_box.x1) / 3
cm.cax.set_position(dendro_box)
cm.cax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("left")
```

Let me know if you can help. thanks